# como hacer un filtro de búsqueda en un gridview asp.net-vb

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

necesito una ayuda ,alguien me puede decir como hacer un filtro en un gridview asp.net(vb) , tengo el diseño(un text box y un button) pero la parte de codificacion me esta tomando tiempo,soy nuevo en asp.net, los datos los obtengo de un bd en sqlserver.

Comment: buen día
Échale un vistazo a este [Enlace](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Filter-GridView-with-TextBox-using-FilterExpression-in-SqlDataSource-in-ASPNet.aspx) y nos cuentas como te va saludos

Comment: Gracias por el enlace pero no se como aplicarlo a mi caso, que parte va en el button , el grid view lo tengo diseñado

Comment: hola, por curiosidad, llegaste a hacer funcionar el filtro?

Answer (score 2):

Te paso un ejemplo en el que justo estoy trabajando ahora, también estoy muy verde en asp.net, pero espero que te sirva:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="campo_para_buscar" HeaderText="campo_para_buscar" SortExpression="campo_para_buscar" />
        </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="Tu_Cadena_Conexion"SelectCommand="SELECT [campo_para_buscar], [el_resto_de_tus_datos] FROM [Tu_Tabla] WHERE ([campo_para_buscar] LIKE '%' + @campo_para_buscar+ '%')">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" DefaultValue="%%" Name="campo_para_buscar" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Todo esto lo he realizado con la propia herramienta de Visual Studio, sin escribir una sola línea de código.

Crea un text_box
Configura el origen de datos del **Grid View**, creas la conexión con tu BD.
Selecciona la opción de: "Especificar columnas de una tabla o vista", puedes dejar marcado el *(buscar todo), o seleccionar los campos que desees.

A la derecha, tendrás un "Where":
Seleccionas la columna.
Operador → "Like".
Origen → "Control".
Id. de control → "como_se_llame_tu_text_box"
Valor predeterminado → %%
Esto último, es importante, porque le añades un valor por defecto, que muestra todas las filas de esa tabla...

Le das a "Agregar", "Aceptar", Siguiente, Consulta de prueba(para verificar que funciona) y por último Finalizar.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, necesitaba poder cambiar la columna a filtrar, por ejemplo, filtrar por código o nombre:

[asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBuscar" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem Value="1">Codigo</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="2">Nombre</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBuscar" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ></asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="nombreSP" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <FilterParameters>
           <asp:ControlParameter Name="Nombre" ControlID="txtBuscarCliente" PropertyName="Text" />
   </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

y en el TextChanged del textbox le asigno valor al FilterExpression:

Code Behind [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net):

```
Select Case ddlBuscar.SelectedValue
   Case 1
      SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Codigo = {0}"
   Case 2
      SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Nombre like '%{0}%'"
End Select
SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters(0).DefaultValue = txtBuscar.Text
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Answer (score -1):

Las opciones que podemos usar para cargar los datos son un forma del gridview, repeater o listview para hacer la conexion usaremos linq 
--Seleccionamos listview.
--Hacemos referencia a las librerias.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sy2J7cUv0QM

Comment: Buenas tardes. Si respondes por favor coloca la solución o algunas ideas que lleven a ella. Si compartes un vídeo tutorial ponlo como comentario.